# How to give the just clicked object to a function? Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script, where assuming ReadyingSmite, a boolean from another function called HeroAbilities, is active after i click a cube, it gives me the information of said cube and activates a function, Smite,  which damages the cube, destroying it if the damage is high enough. How do i make it so Smite knows which cube to damage and destroy?

Script for detecting what cubes was just clicked

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (HeroAbilities.ReadyingSmite && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
     
                GameObject clickedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
                Vector3 clickedPosition = hit.collider.transform.position;

                
                HeroAbilities.Smite();
            }
        }
    }
```

And the Smite script

```
public void Smite()
    {
        int AbilityDamage = Range(7, 10);
        int Damage = crusaderscript.BaseDamage + AbilityDamage ;
        ClickedObject.Health -= Damage ;
        if(ClickedObject.Health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(ClickedObject);
        }
    }
```

I need the places where "ClickedObject" is to be a reference to the clicked cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We pass in the object we just clicked into our Smite function which will destroy it if health >= 0

```
private void Update()
{
    if (HeroAbilities.ReadyingSmite && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit))
        {
            // check if hit object has the expected component attached
            if(hit.collider.TryGetComponent<TheScriptThatRefrenceTheHealth>(out var clickedObject))
            {
                // We pass in our clicked Object that we want to destroy
                HeroAbilities.Smite(clickedObject); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// we make this function receive a TheScriptThatRefrenceTheHealth 
public void Smite(TheScriptThatRefrenceTheHealth clickedObject)
{
    var AbilityDamage = Range(7, 10);
    var Damage = crusaderscript.BaseDamage + AbilityDamage ;
    clickedObject.Health -= Damage ;
    if(clickedObject.Health  <= 0)
    {
        Destroy(clickedObject.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to suggest a few things to improve the answer. 
First is better to use the "TryGetComponent<>()" just in case it doesn't get the specific component it will not hit any exception error.
Second is better to do the "TryGetComponent<>()" inside the Raycast if statement and then pass the component inside the "Smite()" method. With this way in case you don't get the right component it will not execute any other code.

Comment: Also you need to check with "TryGetComponent<>()" that the output is not null, if it's null you should execute return

Comment: @PavlosMavris Hello, could you show me where specifically I should put the trygetcomponents? replacing the getcomponents with trygetcomponents doesnt work.

Comment: I will edit my answer

Comment: That is not how you use `TryGetComponent` .... I edited your answer

Comment: true I totally forgot to do the rest of the stuff  , Thanks ..